# Spartacus Migration Throw error on load of PDP

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I am migrating existing project with Spartacus. When I load Home page its look fine. but PDP page is not look correct. I see some console log in browser.

I have attached screen for reference.

Can someone please help[image: PDP page]

Comment: Hi, can you provide more details about which version of Spartacus are you using? Also ensure that there is no recursive loop somewhere in your code.

Comment: I am using version 3 and I have not customize any component, I just created sample data as per my custom Project. No code change only impex data modified. Also I did init and now PDP is not loading, all call is success in network tab below error.  Thanks for help!                                                               {
   "errors" : [ {
      "message": "There is no resource for path /occ/v2/nisbets-uk-spa/orgProducts/CF841",
      "type": "UnknownResourceError"
   } ]
}